# Using mixins during code parsing in Ruby

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, mixins, thor

I want my `Configurable` module to include a `config` command to whatever app includes it.

**edit**: see the *update* on my reasoning a little further down

I get that error:

```
cli.rb:2:in '<module:Configurable>': undefined method 'desc' for Configurable:Module (NoMethodError)
```

I want to do the following in a commandline:

```
$ app something
> I did something!
$ app config
> You configured the app!
> I did something!
```

So here's the code:

```
# app.rb 

require 'thor'
require_relative './cli'

class App < Thor
    include Configurable

    # def initialize ...

    desc "something", "The Cli app does something"
    def something
        puts "I did something!"
    end
end

# cli.rb 
module Configurable
    desc 'config', "You can configure the app"
    def config
        puts "You configured the app!"
        # You can even call App 'something' method
        something 
    end
end
```

As the above points out, when I comment out the `desc 'config' ..` line, it builds and runs, although Thor doesn't add the `config` command.

Thanks for your help!

#### UPDATE

I downloaded Thor's repo, and added traces when it encountered a `desc` command. So I tried calling `Thor.desc` instead, and I could see that it was loaded in Thor's system, but still didn't appear in commands list. So I played around and ended up with the following:

```
module Configurable
  Thor.desc 'config', 'You can configure the app'
  def config
    puts "You configured the app!"
    # You can even call App 'something' method
    something 
  end

  def self.included(klass)
    puts "The module was included"
    klass.desc "another", "another one"
  end

  def another
    puts "Another!"
  end
end
```

This way, I tested if calling desc before or after made a difference, but it didn't.

At this point, I would say **it's Thor's limitations**, and I can't achieve what I want with Thor and mixins.

Answer (score 1):

`desc` is a method of `Thor`'s singleton class, but `Configurable` isn't an instance of `Thor`'s singleton class. (Obviously.) That's why you can't call `desc` without a receiver, you will have to call it explicitly:

(Note: I don't have Thor, therefore, I cannot test this. It may or may not work.)

```
module Configurable
  Thor.desc 'config', 'You can configure the app'
  def config
    puts "You configured the app!"
    # You can even call App 'something' method
    something 
  end
end
```

Comment: It prevents the "no method" error, but it actually doesn't help. I believe there is no way to achieve what I want by mixins, due to Thor's limitation. I will edit my question and add my reasoning.